# How to replace within a capture group

Tags: regex, sublimetext

I am modifying an existing HTML doc. I'm doing things like adding a table of contents etc.

I have a heading with this ID: `id="transcending intellectual limitations"` (for real!)

I want to be able to find the whole ID, and then replace the spaces with hyphens.

It would be simple if I had just the IDs but I don't want to remove all the spaces in the whole document.

I'm reasonably new to regex, I'm using Sublime's find and replace to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use

```
(?:\bid="|(?!^)\G)[^\s"]*\K\s+
```

And replace with anything you need to replace spaces with.

The `(?:\bid="|(?!^)\G)` pattern sets the initial boundary: either `id="` or the end of the last successful match. This pattern presents an alternation list with two alternatives. `\b` matches a word boundary so that `id="` is matched as a whole word. The `\G` operator matches at the start of the string and after ech successful match. To exclude the start position, a negative `(?!^)` lookahead is added (*not followed with a string start position*).
**See more about `\G`** in ["Where You Left Off: The `\G` Assertion"](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl2/prog/ch05_06.htm#ch05-sect-posit).

The `[^\s"]*` matches zero or more characters other than whitespace and a quote.

The `\K` operator makes the regex engine omit all the text matched so far from the match buffer.

The `\s+` finally matches one or more whitespaces that will be replaced.

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wR4fJ6/4)

Comment: A little explanation on setting the boundary will be great.

Comment: @noob: on a mobile, I do not have edit link any longer since an edit is pending, and I cannot check if the regex demo is working since regex101 is not working on mobiles. The initial boundary is an alternation list with two alternatives. `\b` matches a word boundary so that `id="` is matched as a whole word. `\G` operator matches at the start of the string and after ech successful match. To exclude the start position, I added a negative `(?!^)` lookahead.

Comment: BTW, SublimeText uses Boost library and it is very similar (but not identical to) PCRE. This pattern will work in both engines.

Comment: Wow!  This is an awesome solution, Wiktor!  

Comment: BTW, SublimeText3 uses PCRE. SublimeText 2 had a different regex implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a 2 pass solution using Ruby as the regex parser:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

line = 'yadayadayadaid="transcending intellectual limitations"yadayadayada'
line =~ /id="(.*)"/
part = $1.gsub( /\s+/, '-' )
print part
```

yields:

```
transcending-intellectual-limitations
```

Note that this will replace all whitespace between the words on the 2nd pass.