# RegEx: Match Within Bounded Groups

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to match carriage-returns in blocks of text between a pre-determined tag and an indeterminate tag.

In this case, the bounding tags are:

Pre-determined: `X-Gmail-Labels:`

Indeterminate: `(?:^[\w\-]+:)` eg: `Delivered-To:` or `ABC123:`

Thanks to Wiktor Stribiżew for his answer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34973192/how-to-replace-within-a-capture-group), I have a rough idea of the solution I should pursue.

I am unsure of how to apply what I believe is needed: an uncaptured lookahead group for the bounding indeterminate tag.

Plainly stated, I'd like to delete all the carriage-returns in the text associated with the `X-Gmail-Labels:`. If I can match them, I can delete them!

Initial attempted regex:

`(?:\bX-Gmail-Labels:|(?!^)\G)[^\r]*\K\r`

Sample data:

```
From 1604610346950104244@xxx Fri Jun 29 12:34:35 +0000 2018
X-GM-THRID: 1604610346950104244
X-Gmail-Labels: Archived thing,Unread
Delivered-To: joe.schmoe@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:a9f:3005:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id h5-v6csp731836uab;
        Fri, 29 Jun 2018 05:34:36 -0700 (PDT)
From 1604610346950104244@xxx Fri Jun 29 12:34:35 +0000 2018
X-GM-THRID: 1604610346950104244
X-Gmail-Labels: Also Archived 
Day-of-week: Tuesday
Received: by 2002:a9f:3005:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id h5-v6csp731836uab;
        Fri, 29 Jun 2018 05:34:36 -0700 (PDT)
From 1604610346950104244@xxx Fri Jun 29 12:34:35 +0000 2018
X-GM-THRID: 1604610346950104244
X-Gmail-Labels: Archived 
thing,
Unread
Favorite-fruit: bananas
Received: by 2002:a9f:3005:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id h5-v6csp731836uab;
        Fri, 29 Jun 2018 05:34:36 -0700 (PDT)
From 1604610346950104244@xxx Fri Jun 29 12:34:35 +0000 2018
X-GM-THRID: 1604610346950104244
X-Gmail-Labels: Archived 
 ,Read
ABC123: DoReMe
Received: by 2002:a9f:3005:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id h5-v6csp731836uab;
        Fri, 29 Jun 2018 05:34:36 -0700 (PDT)
From 1604610346950104244@xxx Fri Jun 29 12:34:35 +0000 2018
X-GM-THRID: 1604610346950104244
X-Gmail-Labels: Archived 
thing,Unread
emais
Received: by 2002:a9f:3005:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id h5-v6csp731836uab;
        Fri, 29 Jun 2018 05:34:36 -0700 (PDT)
```

---

`(?:^[\w\-]+:)`

Above regex [applied to data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgPdC.jpg) showing indeterminate tag pattern.

`(?:\bX-Gmail-Labels:\G)[^\r]*\K\r`

Above regex [applied to data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVrVw.jpg) showing un-end-bounded matches.

Thanks!
-Fitz

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://regex101.com/r/PBkoUb/1)?

Comment: Hey Dawg! Thank you for your quick response. It looks like you understand what I'm looking for. I'm specifically attempting to match the carriage-returns between the tags. Your regex appears to be leading me in the right direction. In fact, the online debugger you're using is a superb resource! What I need to do is convert 


this:

`X-Gmail-Labels: Archived 

thing,Unread

emails

Received: by 2002:a9f:3005:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id h5-v6csp731836uab`


to this:

`X-Gmail-Labels: Archived thing,Unreademails

Received: by 2002:a9f:3005:0:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id h5-v6csp731836uab`

Comment: Apologies for the poor formatting above; I haven't too much experience on StackOverflow.

Comment: You should the input / desired output to your question. It is not obvious in a comment what you are looking for.

Comment: Are you using EmEditor? Did you enable Onigmo engine there? And please make your example a bit more concise, with a clear sample input and expected output.

Comment: Hey Dawg, [here's a visual](https://i.imgur.com/au52hHa.jpg) of what I'm trying to end up with.

Comment: Hey Wiktor! Thanks for chiming-in. Yes, I am using [EmEditor and have the Onigmo engine](https://i.imgur.com/fhoMOrB.jpg). I'm dealing with a 12-Gigabyte file, and was hoping to avoid needing to script a solution; was going to simply find-and-replace using regex.

Comment: I am not sure it will work, but try: [`(?m)(?:\G(?!\A)|^X-Gmail-Labels:).*\K\R(?!Received:)`](https://regex101.com/r/PBkoUb/2) and replace with a space.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, I’ll have a look at this over the next day. I really appreciate your and Dawg’s help.

Comment: Next time you comment, please add `@`+username.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: thanks again for your very useful input. I have ended up updating the open-source script that was causing me problems with some required text-scrubbing to alleviate the issue I was experiencing. The idiosyncrasies of the data I was trying to extract with the flavors of regex available to me were just complicating a solution, but you guys opened my eyes to a few tricks that will certainly aid me in the future.

Comment: So, shall we close this question or would you like to remove it?