# RegEx matching only within a match / restrict matching to part of string

Tags: regex

Is there a way to use a single regular-expression to match only within another math. For example, if I want to remove spaces from a string, but only within parentheses:

```
source : "foobar baz blah (some sample text in here) and some more"

desired: "foobar baz blah (somesampletextinhere) and some more"
```

In other words, is it possible to restrict matching to a specific part of the string?

Comment: Basically, you're intending to replace within a capture group. Hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34973192/how-to-replace-within-a-capture-group

Comment: In what language/tool? Different features are supported among regex flavors.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to replace any space between parentheses using a lookahead pattern:

```
 (?=([^\s\(]+ )*\S*\))(?!\S*\s*\()`
```

The lookahead will attempt to match the last space before the closed parenthesis (`\S*\)`) and any optional space before `([^\s\(]+ )*` (if found).

Detailed Regex Explanation:

- : space
- `(?=([^\s\(]+ )*\S*\))`: lookahead non-capturing group

  - `([^\s\(]+ )*`: any combination characters not including the open parenthesis and the space characters + space (this group is optional)
  - `\S*\)`: any non-space character + closed parenthesis
- `(?!\S*\s*\()`: what lookahead should not be

  - `\S*`: any non space character (optional), followed by
  - `\s*`: any space character (optional), followed by
  - `\(`: the open parenthesis

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/quCyWw/1).

Comment: This works without PCRE, so it's what I'll use when using Rename Regex to shorten filenames by stripping out spaces within specific parts. Thanks.

Comment: This only works if the text between the parentheses contains spaces; if not, it targets the spaces _outside_ the parentheses (so you can't run it more than once).

Comment: Correct. Check the updated answer. @Synetech

Comment: Hmm, that works with the sample text you used, but if you put any kind of non-alphanumeric character in the text before the parentheses (eg `foobar baz! (some…`), then it will eat the spaces in that text, but the text after the parenthetical is immune. I tried to debug it, but couldn't sort it out because you only used `\s` and `\S`, not any character-classes that would/should specify only alphanumeric characters. I'm almost inclined to think it's a bug. 

Answer (score 1):

In PCRE a combination of [`\G`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) and [`\K`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) can be used:

```
(?:\G(?!^)|\()[^)\s]*\K\s+
```

- `\G` continues where the previous match ended
- `\K` resets beginning of the reported match
- `[^)\s]` matches any character [not](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) in the set

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xMSZIf/1)

The idea is to chain matches to an opening parentheses. The chain-links are either `[^)\s]*` or `\s+`. To only get spaces `\K` is used to reset before. This solution does not require a closing `)`.

---

In other regex flavors that support `\G` but not `\K`, [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) can help out. Eg Search for

```
(\G(?!^)|\()([^)\s]*)\s+
```

and replace with [captures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982824/what-does-1-2-etc-mean-in-regular-expressions) of the 2 groups (depending on lang: `$1$2` or `\1\2`) - [Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/ORDZhm/1)

---

Further there is [`(*SKIP)(*F)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex), a [PCRE feature](https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html#SEC27) for skipping over certain parts. It is often used together with [The Trick](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick). The idea is simple: `skip this(*SKIP)(*F)|match that` - [Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/pcB7Yt/1). Also this can be worked around with *capture groups*. Eg replace [`([^)(]*\(|\)[^)(]*)|\s` with`$1`](https://regex101.com/r/7IIMhx/1)

Comment: It turns out that Rename Regex (a tool to rename files with regular-expressions) doesn't support PCRE. But it's open-source, so maybe I'll add that. But thanks for the suggestion, it certainly works when PCRE is available.

Comment: @Synetech Welcome, yea a lookahead is certainly more compatible. I also tried to address the question title *restrict matching to part of string*. For this `\G` can be certainly useful but also the `(*SKIP)(*F)` technique mentioned if PCRE is used. The [last solution mentioned](https://regex101.com/r/7IIMhx/1) works in pretty every regex flavor that supports capturing groups. No worries, just loving such questions :)